# cUrl - store everything from a webpage

Tags: php, curl

i'm saving cookies in a text file by using this function:

```
$cookie_file_path = "".dirname(__FILE__)."/cookie.txt"; // Please set your Cookie File path
$fp = fopen($cookie_file_path,'wb'); 
fclose($fp);
$ch = curl_init();
// other curl functions here // 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
$loginpage_html = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

it saves cookies to the same folder as cookie.txt, and it uses same cookies while connecting.

i'd like to save images (css,scripts+everythings) to the same folder. any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using php DOM extension http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php
It's quit similiar to javascript. You just loop thru typical tags like `<img>, <script> <style>,` search for attributes src and get links to referenceing resources and retrieve those contents using the same cURL or file_get_contents.

Check out the DOM manual, it has a lot of useful comments.

Answer (score 0):

try wget with the recursive switch

Comment: If you're on linux (and you have command line access) this is a very good option. You can use PHP to populate the arguments http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php

Comment: +1 for putting into right context. i prefer the classic approach of passing my shell commands directly to system(), passthru() or shell_exec() way ;) altough popen() offers great possibilites when it comes to multi threading and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

First I see you create the file using fopen and fclose, you can just use the function touch for that.

cURL is only used to get the contents of requested page. What you can do is then parse the HTML for links and use cURL in a loop to get those.

There is an set_opt CURLOPT_FILE which is where the output will go. For example:

```
<?php

foreach($links as $link){
    $file = dirname(__FILE__)."/".basename($link);
    touch($file);
    // get page
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $file);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
}

?>
```

I didn't check that code, but thats a base for what you want. Just use regex or some functions to get the links.